# 'EmployeeDetails' does not implement interface member 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, class, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I am trying to implement `Inotifypropertychange` interface, such as

```
public class EmployeeDetails:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 private int employeeID;
    public int EmployeeID
    {
        get { return employeeID; }
        set { employeeID = value; this.NotifyPropertyChanged("EmployeeId"); }
    }

    private string employeeName;
    public string EmployeeName
    {
        get { return employeeName; }
        set { employeeName = value; this.NotifyPropertyChanged("EmployeeName"); }
    }

    private decimal salary;
    public decimal Salary
    {
        get { return salary; }
        set { salary = value; this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Salary"); }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler propertychange;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (propertychange != null)
            propertychange(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
    public EmployeeDetails(int employeeId, string employeeName, decimal salary)
    {
        EmployeeID = employeeID;
        EmployeeName = employeeName;
        Salary = salary;
    }

    public EmployeeDetails()
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
    }
```

}

while debuging, it shows the following error:

'EmployeeDetails' does not implement interface member 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChange

what particular code i missing, please help
i have included the `system.component` assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code

```
public class EmployeeDetails : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  ...
}
```

And you right click on INotifyPropertyChanged, firstly you execute resolve reference and select implement interface

Comment: I'am happy to help you Abhishek